# Eclipse bad indentation warning

Tags: python, eclipse, warnings

I am using PyDev perspective.  I get a "bad indentation" warning in python files.  I am using two spaces for indent and eclipse seems to want me to use 4.

How to set the indentation I want so this warning goes away?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to change the tab length that PyDev uses at:

window > preferences > pydev > editor > tab length

Answer (score 6):

Do Control+A to select all. Then go under the "source" menu tab and select "correct indentation".

Source: currently have Eclipse open.

Comment: You can also do Control+A to select all and then Control+/ to correct indentation.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to change the indentation, I want to change the eclipse default.

Comment: In that case: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect my python files

Answer (score 3):

Warning:

**Bad indentation (2 spaces)**

Solution:

1. **CTRL A** (select all code in current file)
2. **Source -> Convert tabs to space-tabs** [In main menu bar]
3. **Write 2**